# Does Hyland Onbase provide an API that we can consume in a mobile app?

Tags: content-management-system

I need to provide a facility to approve a document through their mobile device.

Does Hyland Onbase provide an API that we can use in a mobile app for approver?

Answer (score 0):

Hyland Software offers a Mobile Application that will allow for use in Workflow or merely document retrieval. They also have a very robust API option.

Comment: My understanding is that to use their api you have to take a 2 week training class from OnBase and get certified.

Answer (score 0):

The new version of Onbase have an Rest API that let you acces workFlow functionality from your program, you will need to check the license to make it work.